# abs(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given

Tags: php, php-8

I want to preview pdf, but not open after updated to php 8 and some package update.
This code notif from laravel

```php
function konversi($x)

    {

        $x = abs($x);

        $angka = array("", "Satu", "Dua", "Tiga", "Empat", "Lima", "Enam", "Tujuh", "Delapan",   "Sembilan", "Sepuluh", "Sebelas");

        $temp = "";

 
> if ($x < 12) {// Notif from laravel in this line


            $temp = " " . $angka[$x];

        } else if ($x < 20) {

            $temp = konversi($x - 10) . " Belas";

        } else if ($x < 100) {

            $temp = konversi($x / 10) . " Puluh" . konversi($x % 10);

        } else if ($x < 200) {

            $temp = " Seratus" . konversi($x - 100);

        } else if ($x < 1000) {

            $temp = konversi($x / 100) . " Ratus" . konversi($x % 100);

        } else if ($x < 2000) {

            $temp = " Seribu" . konversi($x - 1000);

        } else if ($x < 1000000) {

            $temp = konversi($x / 1000) . " Ribu" . konversi($x % 1000);

        } else if ($x < 1000000000) {

            $temp = konversi($x / 1000000) . " Juta" . konversi($x % 1000000);
```

And this notif preview, Type Error

> abs(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given (View: C:\Users\Fauzan Azhim\Downloads\sci-tkdn-fixing_laporan\sci-tkdn-fixing_laporan\resources\views\laporan\cetak_permen_1.blade.php)

Comment: As the error message says, you passed a string to a function that expected an integer or float. Please see: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

> abs(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given
> (View: C:\Users\Fauzan
> Azhim\Downloads\sci-tkdn-fixing_laporan\sci-tkdn-fixing_laporan\resources\views\laporan\cetak_permen_1.blade.php)

1. The error comes from your blade file.
2. change in this blade file `abs($num)` to `abs((int) $num)`
3. Try again.

Comment: 'function konversi($x)
{
  $x = abs((int) $x)
'
int? with number or int just like that?

Comment: @AzhimyFzn it depeds what you are expect. But in your case it would be a int.  but can you dump out $x and share it, please? `dump($x);`. Put the dump on top in your function.